# Multisite features

Tags: multisite

I was thinking about creating a network of user-created blogs. I've read somewhere about wordpress multisite feature, and i was wondering if this is what i'l looking for...
What i need to do is create a website where users register and create their onw blog. 
Does wordpress multisite offer this feature out of the box ? If not, would manually implementing this feature into wp be doable, or should i start from 0 or another platform ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress multisite sounds exactly like what you are looking for. It takes a little work to get multisite set up, but once that's done, the options for allowing anybody to register and create a new site are built right in. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network for setting up a multisite instance.

Comment: thanks! and can it be set up not to use subdomains ? meaning insted of newuser.mysite.com to be smth like mysite.com/newuser ?

Comment: Yes, multisite can be set up to use subdirectories instead of subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MultiSite feature handles your desired setup, out of the box.